# How to form a professional project in python?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am learning python especially in machine learning and computer vision. Recently, I was trying to examine codes of some papers in Github. One thing I got, is that writing codes for papers are much different from tutorials on internet. They are much more complicated, comprising of many different folders and .py files named such as utils.py, main.py, train.py, **init**.py etc. I have some questions regarding this matter. Firstly, does the name of these files created automatically using something or they are created manually by writers? Secondly, if it is automatically, how can I create such coding style and if they are done manually, is there any standard format for naming or coding that I should use? Finally, is there any reference to teach how to create such standard coding styles?

Comment: Hot take: "Professional" is a [weasel word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word).

Comment: I have been using [Kedro](https://kedro.org/) for ML orchestration although [there are others](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataengineering/comments/1152wow/which_ml_orchestration_tool_fits_my_use_case/).

Comment: You might find this [data engineering wiki](https://dataengineering.wiki/Index) interesting.

Comment: For coding style in Python, just use [black](https://github.com/psf/black) or similar and setup an appropriate PyLint config. I tend to use either the default PyLint or Google's Pylint config.

Comment: Also, some of us like it [Ruff](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/).

Comment: Thank you Galen for these useful resources. That is what I was looking for.